# Backbone collection fetch specific data from json

Tags: json, backbone.js

Hi, I have the following JSON:

```
[
    {"id":"1","question":"Whats is your name ?","type":"Text","source":"-","default":"-","control":"-","requestDate":"Yes","required":"Yes"},
    {"id":"2","question":"What is your Age ?","type":"Text","source":"-","default":"-","control":"-","requestDate":"No","required":"No"},
    {"id":"3","question":"What is your interest?","type":"Text","source":"-","default":"-","control":"-","requestDate":"Yes","required":"No"},
    {"id":"4","question":"What is your qualification?","type":"Text","source":"-","default":"-","control":"-","requestDate":"Yes","required":"Yes"},
    {"id":"5","question":"What is your Nic ?","type":"Text","source":"-","default":"-","control":"-","requestDate":"Yes","required":"No"}
]
```

now I have to fetch the data from json whose id is provided during fetching, I want to fetch the data by id parameter. for example the fetch result provide that json object

```
{"id":"1","question":"Whats is your name ?","type":"Text","source":"-","default":"-","control":"-","requestDate":"Yes","required":"Yes"}
```

if I provide the id=1 in collection.fetch event.. any method ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for:

```
collection.fetch({ data: $.param({ id: 1}) });
```

You'll have to add some code server side too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that JSON in Backbone Collection. You can get specific Model by passing in an id, cid or Model object. In your case

```
 myModel = collection.get(1);
```

where collection should be whatever your collection instance is

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the json data already, and want to filter it to just the one matching record, you can use [findWhere](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere):

```
myModel = collection.findWhere({id: 1});
```